# Using the Twilio Client API can you answer a specific caller in the queue

Tags: twilio

I can successfully answer the first caller in the queue by using the `.connect()` Twilio Client API function but is there way to answer a specific caller.

For example my call center will we able to see the names of the callers (using our own system matching numbers to users) and sometimes a specific call center agent will need answer a specific users call. So let's assume that there are 3 people in queue and the agent needs to be the one to talk to person 2 without having to wait for someone else to answer person 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

As far as I know there is no way to use the `<Dial>` verb to connect to a specific caller in a Queue.  You can however dequeue a specific caller using the REST API:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/member#instance-post-example-2

So when an agent clicks the specific caller they want to connect to that could kick off a process that dequeues that specific caller and drops them into a conference, while the agents cal is also redirected in to that same conference.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I'll need to look more into how to dequeue the caller and kick them into something else. I think we will probably end up have a main queue plus a queue for each agent and so if they "claim" a user in the main queue we can just move them to the agent's queue and I can write some JS to `.connect` to their personal queue once they claim the user. Thanks!